# Rubik race solving algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, backtracking, rubiks-cube

I am trying to write an algorithm for solving RUBIK Race. It is a 5 * 5 board with each cell either having a color RED, WHITE, YELLOW, GREEN, BLUE, ORANGE or an EMPTY cell. ie, There will be 4 cells for each color, and 1 EMPTY cell. The cells on LEFT, RIGHT, TOP, BOTTOM of the EMPTY cell can be moved to the place of EMPTY cell, and thats how a change is made to the current arrangement of 5 * 5 board.
Also there will be a 3 * 3 board which has a cube with the above mentioned colors in each of its cells. This 3 * 3 board is shuffled and the 5 * 5 board has to rearranged so that the center 3 * 3 sub matrix of 5 * 5 board must be equal to the 3 * 3 board.
The RUBIK race is played between 2 players , and the first person to solve wins.

The detailed game rules are find below.
This is the link for RUBIK's race https://www.rubiks.com/en-us/rubik-s-race.html

I started with a simple brute force algorithm which checks all possible states and when the desired state is reached it finds the list of movements made to the initial state of board.
I have defined 4 types of movements for each state of 5 * 5 board. They are move LEFT, RIGHT, TOP, BOTTOM.
The below picture will explain my algorithm.

[image]

As it is evident that this solution is absolutely inefficient. It checks all the possibilities. ie, for a 5 * 5 board possibilities are close to (25!)/ (4! * 4! * 4! * 4! * 4! * 4!).

I tried giving ranks to each child possibilities and consider only the possibility which has greater rank. Even that approach is also ineffecient.

What kind of optimisations are possible for this particular problem?

Comment: not familiar with the game looks like it has nothing to do with Rubik's cube , its more similar to game of 15 or 16 sliding puzzle? Those are usually solved using A* path finding

Comment: This is a classic sliding puzzle, except that only `9` squares need to match an orientation, so there are at least millions of valid solutions. Iterative deepening A* (IDA*) is the usually recommended solution. The tricky part of this problem is choosing a good (admissible, consistent, and fairly accurate) heuristic. One possible heuristic is the sum of Manhattan distances between each square in the center 3x3 to the nearest square of its target color. More sophisticated heuristics will give better performance.